# MS Access 2010 Synchronization issue

Tags: ms-access-2010

Description. MS Access 2010, mdb database. 
Number of notebooks contain replicas of the main database located on the shared drive.

Usual procedure for users to update data on their local copy is to go to Database tools -> Replication options -> Synchronize now. Then a dialogue window opens with the path to the main database and process starts. Recently everyone was starting to get an error before window opens with "

> There isn't enough memory to perform this operation. Close unneeded
>   programs and try the operation again

" But after clicking OK everything went as usual.

Now we got into the situation that after the error message dialogue window with the path to the main database is not opening and we can't update the data. We have used older backups to exclude corruption, made new replicas, freed memory. Strange thing is that one is able to synchronize during the first couple of hours and the situation repeats again.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I would like to get help to understand how to get things back. Why the dialogue box is not opening anymore?